# How to create mbtiles from pbf which will be compatible with TileServer GL?

Tags: mbtiles, pbf, tileserver-gl

I am new to GIS and trying to figure everything out. Right now my goal is to understand how to create an mbtiles vector file that can be served with TileServer GL. I have downloaded the free 2020 mbtiles file that can be easily served with TileServer GL, but I'd like to learn to make my own from current 2023 data. And I couldn't find any information about how to actually do it.

From what I understand, pbf downloaded from OSM contains just a dump of all roads, all areas of earth etc in a single list, and this is not displayable on a map, because, for example, one needs to filter the small items out when displaying a larger area of the map.

From what I understand, mbtiles I have downloaded contain pyramid tiles of zoom 0-14 which contain vector data with objects too small filtered out

Now question is, how do I make such a pyramid tilemap mbtiles file, when I have a pbf file on hand?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, [Tilemaker](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker) might be one option.  It runs standalone, is easily testable on a small area from e.g. [Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/), and comes with [a couple of example configurations](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/tree/master/resources); one that's very simple and easy to understand, and one that's more OMT-like.